# How to assign axios response to a constant and return the const with assigned value in React

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-typescript

The below mentioned code does not set the values to response constant and I am not able to return it.

```
    export const calculateData= async ({
      assetId,
      mappings,
    }: {
      assetId: number;
      mappings: MappingDIn[];
    }) => {
  const response = await axios.post<ClassModal>(
          `/api/assets/${assetId}/calculateData`, mappings).then(response=>
        {
         console.log(response)}).catch(error=>{console.error(error)});
       return response;
    };
```

Comment: Generally: don't mix `await`/`async` and `.then`/`.catch` in the same function. Your then callback doesn't return the value, so overall it's a promise of undefined.

Answer (score 0):

```
export const calculateData = async ({
    assetId,
    mappings,
}: {
    assetId: number;
    mappings: MappingDIn[];
}) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post<ClassModal>(`/api/assets/${assetId}/calculateData`, mappings);
        return response;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(error);
    }
}
```

Async function will always return a Promise. If you return anything else, it will wrap it in a Promise object.

Either use async / await or use Promise (.then, .catch, .finally), but don't mix them together. You can achieve with both the same results, but some people see async / await as best practice.